# Twilio high volume sender to use only one phone number?

Tags: twilio

in theory would it be possible for a high volume sender to use only one phone number?

For example, would it be possible for a company like Amazon, who sends out a text when a package is delivered, to send all of their SMS' from only one phone number, or are there API limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

This is possible by using a [short code](https://www.twilio.com/sms/shortcodes).  Sending high volumes of messages from a normal 10 digit (in the US) phone number, which are also known as long codes, will likely result in the carriers blacklisting that number.

With Twilio, the only limiting we enforce is rate limiting which means how many messages per second we send to the carriers.  Your application can send messages to Twilio as fast as you want via the REST API.

When sending from long codes we rate limit at 1 message per second.  For short codes the rate limit is 30 messages per second.

More details can be found here:

- https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/what-are-the-limits-on-outbound-calls-and-sms-messages-per-second
- https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-my-twilio-sms-messages-be-blacklisted-as-spam

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. They mentioned that 1 number can send out messages to 200 unique phone numbers. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/copilot-best-practices#146-how-many-people-do-you-want-to-reach  Would you happen to know how many text messages 1 long code can send out? So let's say I have one long code and 200 different phone numbers that I want to send a text message to. How many messages can I send out using that long code? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes, use co-pilot and like said above with 200 or X amount of different phone numbers.